# Update specific value in Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Please how do I update a particular value in a Realm database without refreshing everything, I have used both copyToRealmOrUpdate and insertOrUpdate, the issue is, assuming I have a realm DB class of value ***ID***, ***name*** and ***surname*** if I actually do this:

```
   final MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.setId(42);
obj.setName("Fish");
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()

{
    @Override
    public void execute (Realm realm){
    // This will create a new object in Realm or throw an exception if the
    // object already exists (same primary key)
    // realm.copyToRealm(obj);

    // This will update an existing object with the same primary key
    // or create a new object if an object with no primary key = 42
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj);
}
});
```

it might update ***ID*** 42 to 'name'="fish", but if I query for ***surname*** it will not return a valid value, actually the real code I used in my project is:

```
                final RealmDB_Class realmDB_class = new RealmDB_Class();
            realmDB_class.setPasswordForPrint("2");//no zero so that it can ask one more time
            realmDB_class.setId(1);
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                             realm.insertOrUpdate(realmDB_class);
                                         }
                                     }


            );
```

I just want to update the setpasswordForPrint to '2' while preserving the other values I had earlier saved in the realm database such as a variable called 'name' .
The Issue is that when I query for name, it points to null, probably because I did not re-insert it here. I do not want to have to insert it.

I have tried using **copyToRealmOrUpdate** but it also didn't work. Am I to insert all the values again or isn't there a way to just update one value such as SQL **UPDATE 'A' SET ...WHERE ...** without inserting fresh values. If a 'row' has name, and surname, can't I just update the name using the ID without putting the surname again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute (Realm realm) {
         MyObject obj = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo("id", 42).findFirst();
         if(obj == null) {
             obj = realm.createObject(MyObject.class, 42);
         }
         obj.setName("Fish");
    }
});
```

Or

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
     @Override
     public void execute(Realm realm) {
          final RealmDB_Class realmDB_class = realm.where(RealmDB_Class.class).equalTo("id", 1).findFirst();
          realmDB_class.setPasswordForPrint("2");
     }
});
```

---

`insertOrUpdate()` cannot differentiate between whether a value you're saving is explicitly set to `null` or you've just never initialized it, so to update specific field, you need to use accessor on managed object inside transaction.

Comment: Hey, @EpicPandaForce How to do this operation in bulk update cases? I tried to use InsertOrUpdate. It is updating old values as null in some of the fields whatever I don't want to change. and successfully updating those specific field values whatever I want to update. Any idea how to keep old values in other fields along with new updates on specific fields?

Comment: @PrantikMondal `insertOrUpdate` will overwrite the fields of the class with whatever those values are. Theoretically the right way to do it USED TO BE what you see here, which is to get the managed object, that way you didn't kill the links when saving it back (and saving of mutations was automatic due to managed nature of object). HOWEVER a new API that I was asking for since 2017.05, was added since 5.8.0 (2018-11-06)) called `RealmResults.setValue(fieldName, value)`, that way you can use a `findAll()` but can ditch the `for` loop thus not creating a RealmProxy for each iterated item.

Comment: Technically this meant for me that I could use `insertOrUpdate` to bulk-insert at top-level, but I had to micromanage the links and merge items, and could not rely on `insertOrUpdate` (or I had to make sure the links are still kept, but that requires managed objects anyway). Though I guess the links would also be preserved if the objects have primary keys and they are set up exactly just as they are in DB. But, NULL values WILL be saved as null.